Chuuk for non-divers
Planning to visit Chuuk for a few days. I understand that diving the sunken Japanese ships is the main draw here. I am into WW2 history and would love to see the sunken ships. However, due to ear problems I can't scuba dive.
Are there wrecks that can be snorkeled rather than dived? Or are they all too deep?
I am also interested in WW2 relics on land, such as bunkers, guns, airplane wrecks, etc. (not so much museums). Additionally, some islands have cultural relics, such as the stone money on Yap or the community homes on Palau. Are there WW2 relics or cultural relics like these that would take one or a few days to explore?

https://masterliveaboards.com/how-deep-are-the-truk-lagoon-wrecks/ has a pretty nice graphic. Combined with water clarity you might get a lot of mileage just snorkeling.

I think the answer to your 2nd question (are there ... busy for a few days) is opinion based, so that may be reason for some to downvote, or vote to close. The 1st question should be answerable though.

"Are there WW2 relics and/or cultural relics that would keep you busy for a few days?" is a bit too vague because "WW2 relics" could mean anything, from items in major museums to ruins in distant locations, and from very technical things of interest to specialists to exhibits accessible to the general public. And "cultural relics" likewise. What do you want to see or do?

@StuartF Thanks for your comments. Edited the question to make it more specific.
